# When create checkbox in JavaScript got [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
  data = [{
            name: 'Yemen',
            code: 'YE'
        },
        {
            name: 'Zambia',
            code: 'ZM'
        },
        {
            name: 'Zimbabwe',
            code: 'ZW'
        }
    ];

    function addKeyValue(obj, key, data) {
        obj[key] = data;
    }

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "key";
    checkbox.id = "id";        
    newinfo = data.map(function(person) {
        return addKeyValue(person, 'checkbox', (checkbox));        });

var columnHeadings = Object.keys(data[0]);     
var columnCount = columnHeadings.length;     
var rowCount = data.length;
var table = document.createElement('table');     
document.getElementById("data-list").appendChild(table);    
var header = table.createTHead();     
var row = header.insertRow(-1);     
for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {     
    var headerCell = document.createElement('th');        

    headerCell.innerText = columnHeadings[i].toUpperCase();

    row.appendChild(headerCell);     
}
var tBody = document.createElement('tbody');

table.appendChild(tBody);
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) { // each row
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');        

  row = tBody.insertRow(-1);       
  for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) { // each column       
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);     
    cell.setAttribute('data-label', columnHeadings[j].toUpperCase());

    var obj = data[i];         
    cell.innerText = obj[columnHeadings[j]];

  }     
}
```

In a tabular format I do have to get checkboxes with the json data. So firstly I have defined my json and then I have append checkboxes for each row.I am planning to add check boxes in every `json` object. But in my final output it is giving `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of a checkbox.

Comment: What output?  This code doesn't output anything.  How have you examined your variables to determine whether they are what you expect.  A checkbox *is* an HTML Input Element...

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. You are not appending the checkbox created to the DOM at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the element object to your newinfo array, if you want the html for it you need to add it to the dom which it looks like you want to do at some point later in your code, to do this you would for example do `document.body.appendChild(checkbox)` if you wanted to add the checkbox to body.

Comment: Its not an error, you are storing an element object, as I said in my answer if you want to add the element to the dom you use the appendChild method.